# Module 'connectivity not found' in iOS build of Flutter application

Tags: ios, flutter

I have been trying to build my flutter app in iOS simulator but getting build error with following screenshot.

Where my **Xcode version is 11.0, CocoaPods version 1.9.3, Flutter version 1.22.0**

I have also upgraded connectivity package from 0.4.9+2 to 0.4.9+3 which is latest one. Following some steps by googling but no one is working yet. However my android build is fully ok.

Thanks in advance.

[image]

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I have solved this issue through running this command in terminal at Project folder directory

```
rm ios/Podfile && flutter build ios
```

Comment: I think this is dangerous because this rebuilds the entire ios folder again. ONLY DO THIS IF YOU WANT THIS

Answer (score 18):

I was opening ios/Runner.xcodeproj instead of ios/Runner.xcworkspace.

Opening ios/Runner.xcworkspace from Xcode worked for me!

Answer (score 17):

I solved this problem by setting in the podfile

```
platform :ios, '12.1'
```

And then later inserting the same version in Xcode as well

[image: Xcode]

Comment: This is the only solution that worked for my device.

Comment: This one worked for me as well after minutes of trial and error

Answer (score 3):

If you are working with flavoured build, e.g `staging`, `production`, `development`.

Your app will most likely be running on `Runner` so click on runner and select the correct build build flavour which in this case would be one of the flavours.

Answer (score 3):

My solution:

Firstly, open `ios/Runner.xcworkspace` instead of ios/Runner.xcworkproj.

Then follow the steps:

1. Delete `Podfile` and `Podfile.lock` in the `ios` folder
2. `flutter clean`
3. `flutter pub get`
4. `cd ios` then run `pod install --repo-update`
5. `flutter build ios`

Comment: ```pod install --repo-update``` did it for me

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively, go to your flutter appname/ios folder and type in commandline:

```
   sudo gem install cocoapods
   flutter pub get    <---may or may not be necessary for you
   pod install
```

This will install the infuriating cocoapods to your project

Answer (score 1):

I have this issue and this sequence of steps have worked for me.

1. Go to the ios folder #cd ios
2. Delete the Podfile #rm Podfile
3. Run flutter clean
4. Run flutter pub get
5. Case you need generate files with build_runner #flutter packages pub run build_runner build --delete-conflicting-outputs
6. Build for app for iOS. #flutter build ios
7. Generate your project pods. #cd ios && pod install
8. Build project from XCode

Answer (score 1):

In many cases it comes because of difference between Pod install version in flutter and Xcode. Just check them or simply add 'platform :ios, '11.0'' to your podfile in flutter.

Comment: This answer was already provided, and does not need to be repeated.

Answer (score 1):

1. rm ios/Podfile && flutter build ios
2. Change the platform number on Podfile "platform :ios, '12.1" (in XCode: Pick 12.1v.--> Runner > info IOS Deployment Target: 12.1)
3. Open the flutter ios folder (right-click on ios folder in vs. code and click "Open in   Xcode")
4. Go to Product > Schemes > New Scheme
5. Select the name of your Cocoapod, then click OK

build again

Answer (score 0):

I just fixed but running project via "Runner.xcworkspace"[image]

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me was running flutter create to fix the ios folder.

I actually deleted the ios folder completely (`rm -rf ios`), ran `flutter create <dir>` and then it started building again.

DISCLAIMER: Of course, all my previous ios specific configuration was lost, but that's why we version track everything with git. Then I went over all modified files to actually revert back all my ios customizations.

Answer (score -1):

it's mean som dependencies missing on project. I solved same problem by this step.

```
cd /YourProject/iOS
rm Podfile
```

`flutter clean` On your IDE

```
flutter pub get
```

And `cd /YourProject/iOS`

```
pod install
```

Answer (score -2):

in xode clear build and close xcode
and
run this in project folder.

```
flutter clean && fluttter pub get && cd ios && rm ios/Podfile &&  cd .. &&flutter build ios
```

open xcworkspace instead of xcodeproj.
build the project

Comment: there are so many mistakes in your answer. I think what you wanted to communicate was this:
```flutter clean && flutter pub get && rm ios/Podfile && flutter build ios
```
For me it did not work. Still have the same problem as Mimu

Comment: try deleting pod and pod lock from ios folder then run flutter build ios.